# (PUCHAR)_alligned_malloc using in python

Tags: python, c, dll, malloc

I'v done researched a lot about this problem.. But there's no where and I couldn't find it. I'm trying to using aligned_malloc in python

My question is, how can i transfer to use aligned malloc in python? Second, How I can get GetBufferAddress function? I can't think that i'm right on my way.

[Visual C++/C]

```
 int AapSetBufferAddress(HANDL hDev, int nCh, ULONG ulType, int nMemNum, void* pAddress)

 pUserBuffer = (PUCHAR)_aligned_malloc(X_SIZE * YSIZE * (nBoardBit/8), 16);
 Zero Memory(pUserBuffer, X_SIZE * Y_SIZE * (nBoardBit/8));
 AapSetBufferAddress(Dev, Input_CH, ACL_IMAGE_PTR ,1 , pUserBuffer);
```

[Python]

I changed Python Syntax like this.

```
   def main():
   ...
      aaplib2 = ctypes.WinDLL("AapLib2.dll")
      pUserBuffer = X_SIZE * Y_SIZE * (nBoardBit/8)
      Zeromemory = np.zeros(pUserBuffer, dtype = np.uint16)

      pUserBuffer =[]
      output = PA.GetBufferAddress(Hev,Input_CH, ACL_IMAGE_PTR , 1 , pUserBuffer)
   ... 

   def PA(Hev, CH, ulType, nMemNum, pAddress):
       pAddress.clear()
       p_ValueArr = (ctypes.ubtye * len(pAddress))(*pAddress)
       Func = aaplib2.GetBufferAddress
       Func.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p]
       Func.restype = ctypes.c_int

       ret = func(Hev, CH, ulType, nMemNum, ctypes.addressof(p_ValueArr)
       pAddress.append(p_ValueArr[0])
       return ret
```

Comment: Isn't the `_aligned_malloc` in the C library there? Just like any other function.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019